# Why I cannot receive a characters in C++

Tags: c++, string, character

This is my code to receive string. 
But I don't know what causes a problem. 
Anybody knows?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class person{
private:
    char name[100];
   //char * name;
public:
    person(void) : name(){}
    person(person& myPerson);
    ~person(void) {delete []name;}
    void read();
    void write();
};

person::person(person& myPerson ){
        strcpy(name ,myPerson.name);
    }

void person::read(){
    cout<< "read name from console: " ;
    cin >> name;                   
}
```

//////// <<---- problem point.

```
void person::write(){
    cout << name << endl;
}

void main(void) {
person p1;
p1.read();
//p1.write();

    getchar();   
}
```

//I insert "getchar()" to remain console window for a while

Comment: `void main` is not legal C++. Use `int main`. If you want to make it easy, just use `std::string`. Right now, you're leaving your program open to buffer overflows.

Comment: post your error message please

Comment: You didn't tell us what the problem is. Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: @chris oh... Is it illegal? Thanks I didn't know that. And I will find out what is 'std::string'

Comment: @IvanPavičić I did not think about it. Following is the message.**Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse**

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry. I was not professional because I am a newbie. I am going to try to keep the rules. :)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `delete []name;` from the destructor of `person`.  You should only free memory that is heap allocated, with `malloc()` or `new`, and not space that is stack allocated, like your fixed-size array declared `char name[100]`.  This change will fix the memory error you receive when the destructor is executed as the program exits.

Comment: Thanks! I figure out this.

Comment: @CharlseChoi If this answers your question mark it with the check symbol. Also, make sure you're [informed](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of errors or bad style.

First, it's recommend to use C++ standard library facilities as much as possible. So use `std::string` instead of `char[SIZE]`.

Second, use `int main{return 0;}` instead of `void main{}`.

Third, `delete [] name;` will lead to a memory error. You are freeing stack memory not heap memory.

Last, in my opinion, class names should start with a capital letter (Person).